# Android ContentProvider freeze after writing 65535 bytes

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, outputstream, file-descriptor, limits

I'm using a content provider with an overridden `openFile` method:

```
@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
    ParcelFileDescriptor[] pipe = null;
    InputStream in = null;

    try {
        pipe = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();
        String path = uri.getPath();

        in = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
        PipeFeederThread p = new PipeFeederThread(in, new AutoCloseOutputStream(pipe[1]));
        p.start();

    /*catches.... */

    return (pipe[0]);
}
```

PipeFeederThread contains the usual block-write procedure:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
int len;            
try {
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
        Log.i("WRITE","Writing...");
    }
    Log.i("WRITE","Finished");
    in.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

But when I  try to use my provider with an `ACTION_VIEW` intent like the gallery, the provider only writes 65535 bytes to "out" (the log shows only 8 times) and then nothing happens.
I've made a counter int to break the while loop when we reach the 65535 "limit" but then it'll transfer a corrupted file.

Comment: Well.len can be less than 8192. Log it. And summate.

Comment: `while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        Log.i("WRITE","Writing...");
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
        Log.i("WRITE",String.format("Written %d bytes!",len);
    }`
it goes up to 65536 (8192*8) then only "Writing..." appears and my app is hanging on out.write

Comment: len can not go up to that much as the buf is only 8192.

Comment: Try with a file thats less then 16 bits maxsize.

Comment: Can you give a more comple code sample which we can test?

Comment: sorry I mean len is always 8192 the sum is 65536 :)

Comment: Here's my code:
https://gist.github.com/Silur/1501bdffb03243456b1c

Comment: after some debugging I noticed that my code "dies" in libCore.io line 494 :\

Comment: Well what code is on those lines? You still did not tell what the receiver of the intent - is that the gallery?- should do with your file. Did you already try with a file less than 65 KB?

Comment: `....... overriden methods .....`. Pleqase put complete code. Otherwise i cannot test.

Comment: Can confirm the issue. Had to change `public static final String TAG = "hu.silur.test.MyProvider";` to `public static final String TAG = "hu.silur.test";` before it even would run. I got Google Search??? instead.

Comment: I currently have the same problem. But as i see there isn't a valueable answer yet. Anyone?

Comment: No, I gave up with the project since I didn't found anything about this, something in libCore.io is waiting for eternity and the provider won't get anything

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [ParcelFileDescriptor.open()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor.html#open(java.io.File,%20int)) method. Something like this:

```
private val File.assetFileDescriptor get() = AssetFileDescriptor(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(this, MODE_READ_ONLY), 0, length())
```

And then in your code simply do:

```
return in.assetFileDescriptor
```